# Портативная колонка и аудиокниги, порядок книг и глав

Tags: linux, файловая-система, copy

Нужно подготовить micro-SD карточку с аудиокнигами и музыкой для портативной колонки.
Все предварительно собрал в отдельно директории на компе, потом скпорилова.
Как оказалось, колонка проигрывает все в произвольном (перемешенном) порядке.
Сначала проигрывается, например 5 глава из одной книги, потом 10 из другой, потом 4 из первой и т.д.

Вставил карточку в комп и запустил

```
find . -name *.mp3
```

Команда вывела файлы то порядке, в каком они проигрывались в колонке. Отсюда делаю вывод, что устройство проигрывает файлы в порядке следования в ФС.

Как закинуть на карточку все в нужном порядке (в порядке сортирования по алфавиту)? Кидать по одному не дело, файлов несколько тысяч.

Comment: раньше мой плеер страдал такой же ерундой, я для решения этого писал скрипт, который переименовал все файлы, чтобы они следовали в необходимом порядке

Comment: Хорошо бы увидеть иерархию файлов в каталоге, так же `find . -name *.mp3 | sort` выводит корректно файлы или нет?

Comment: rsync используйте вместо cp. эта программа копирует именно в том порядке, в котором выводит об этом сообщения.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, а как именно копировать?

Comment: https://www.yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%20rsync&lr=2

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая утилита fatsort

1. Копируем файлы любым способом
2. Запускаем

   ]$ sudo fatsort -afc /dev/sdc1

Где `/dev/sdc1` собственно флешка
Программа имеет и другие разнообразные опции сортировки, например можно сортировать по дате и т.д.